# How to call a WCF SOAP web service using Postman

Tags: wcf, soap, postman

I'm following these instructions from the Postman blog to call a WCF (SOAP) web service using Postman:

[Postman makes SOAP requests too](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/11/18/postman-makes-soap-requests-too/)

I keep getting this error message back:

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

There is no security on this particular service prototype and when I examine the WCF service logs I see this message in red:

> Process action''.

Any idea how to get around this problem and map a SOAP Action in the request?

Answer (score 10):

I found a workaround by specifying a request header with a SOAPAction key and value of: `http://tempuri.org/I<My Service Name>/<Method Name>`

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Instead of following Siggi's suggestion of looking at the "Raw" results, I simply looked at the http log provided in SOAPUI 5.5.0 and it was very clear what the SOAPAction was!

Answer (score 1):

If you have called your service in SaopUI client, then  you can get the correct SOAPAction header value there under the Raw tab in the request window in SoapUI.